# Ruby on Rails Development: updating model attribute using f.association collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im currently working on a rails program. It contains many different databases but to keep things simple I have a people, student, and faculty table.

A person can be a student or faculty member and there all connected by the person_id. A faculty member advises students so the student is connected to the faculty member by the id of the faculty.

To create a student you need to select a major and a faculty member(faculty_id). Being that the student and faculty members are all people.. in my dropdown I had to use

```
      <div>
 <%= f.input :faculty_id %>
     <%= f.association :person, label: "Advisor", label_method: :to_label ,  value_method: :id, include_blank: false, collection:  Person.where("role_id=?", @role.id)%>      
  </div>
```

to limit the people in the drop down to only faculty members.

But the issue Im running into now is how would I set the faculty_id attribute of the student with the selected value of the association collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution. As it turns out f.association isnt the only way to limit the dropdown list I created a form helper in my person controller to generate a list of advisors using sql

```
 def set_advisors
   @role = Role.find_by_role_name('advisor')
  @advisors = Person.find_by_sql("SELECT a.id, p.fname FROM faculties as a, people as p                 WHERE a.person_id=p.id AND p.role_id="+@role.id.to_s)
```

end

By doing this I was able to use f.collection_select to update my attribute like so

```
   <div class="field" id="advisorId">
     <%= f.label :faculty_id, 'Advisor' %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:faculty_id, @advisors, :id, :fname) %>
  </div>
```

hope this helps anyone needing to limit there drop down like me :)